# EaselJS not working on mac and in iOS webapp

Tags: javascript, ios, canvas, easeljs, createjs

I have an html file that uses EaselJS for some image animation. It works great on my PC in Chrome and Safari, but when I try to run it on my Mac, it doesn't work in any browser or in my iOS PhoneGap app. I broke my code down to the simplest elements I could to see if I could get that to work, and I can't. The relevant code is below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue();
        queue.addEventListener("complete", init);
        queue.loadFile({id:"img", src:"images/my-image.png"});

        function init() {

            var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
            var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
            var myimg = new createjs.Bitmap(queue.getResult("img"));

            myimg.x = 500;
            myimg.y = 210;

            stage.addChild(myimg);
            stage.update();
        }
    });
</script>

<canvas id="mycanvas" width="1024" height="768"></canvas>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? If I can figure out why this isn't working on my mac, then hopefully I can get my animation working.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to not use Phonegap but instead to try using CocoonJs.